# Upsert contact conditionally

Tags: apex, upsert

I am trying to upsert a contact conditionally if similar contact is found.

```
Step 1: Prepare new contact data
Contact c = new Contact(lastname = 'test', email = 'test@test.com', externalId__c ='12345');
//Step 2: Check existing contacts for duplicates "with some exceptions (and hence I cannot use uniqueness on this field)"
//Step 3: upsert
upsert c externalId__c;
```

If any contact is found in step 2 logic and has same external Id, I should be still able to do the upsert, but donot overwrite existing contact email address.

I am trying not to do additional query but instead just remove the email field from being updated.

Any suggestions ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In step 2, you have to query the contact. Something like this:

```
Contact c = new Contact(LastName='Test', ExternalId__c='12345');
if([SELECT COUNT() FROM Contact WHERE ExternalId__c = :externalId] == 0) {
    // new contact
    c.Email = 'test@test.com';
} else {
    // existing contact
}
upsert c Contact.ExternalId__c;
```

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I thought almost the same, but posted to get if there are any workarounds. Thankyou